# Dell XPS 13 touchpad stopped working

Tags: touchpad, dell, xps

I have a Dell XPS 13 Dev edition with 16.04. Today my touchpad stopped working, I think it was right after I unplugged an external screen. 
Nothing happens if i press or touch the touchpad, the pointer just won't move.

- If I connect an external mouse I am able to use it to move the pointer without problems.
- I know the hardware is not broken because if I boot into Ubuntu 16.04 from a USB stick the touchpad works.

Running

```
synclient touchpadoff=0
```

Did not help. Neither did

```
sudo modprobe i2c_hid
```

Or adding

```
grub_cmdline_linux_default= quiet splash acpi=force
```

to /etc/default/grub.

If i run

```
less /proc/bus/input/devices
```

I see my touchpad, and it is also visible in 
xinput as

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Laser Mouse                  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: Actually just noticed something else, the speakers area also completely dead.  If I go into sound settings I only have: play sound through: dummy output. And it also doesn't work if I plug in a pair of headphones. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm finding the same thing with my laptop :(

Comment: Try to update bios, that fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my trackpad working by using libinout instead if synaptics.

Wrote up what I tried here: [Dell XPS 13 9350 - Trackpad tap works but trackpad click does not](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107347/dell-xps-13-9350-trackpad-tap-works-but-trackpad-click-does-not/1108176)