# Touchpad not responding in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

I admit that I am very new to using a terminal for solutions, but since updating my Ubuntu to 18.04 the touchpad on my laptop has not been responding. I have searched, with the greatest lists of answers coming from this question on this same website:

[Touchpad not working on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041820/touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04)

i worked my way through answers 13, 6 and 1 but none have solved my problem. I looked into the same commands by the person in the above question and I have similar results. I can find the touchpad on a command search:

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01b1
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event5 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 610000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=660800011000003
```

but no amount of changing folder names on grub or installing xserver has solved my problem. The touchpad was working fine until the most recent update I completed, which was about 2 days ago.

I have a Dell Inspiron 11 3000 series with Ubuntu 18.04.03.

Comment: For now, use an external mouse or the previous kernel (4.15.0-70) as suggested in [comment #7](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854798/comments/7) or read the [full bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854798).

Comment: Try if moving to the libinput driver solves the issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107347/dell-xps-13-9350-trackpad-tap-works-but-trackpad-click-does-not